# How do I replace compile-internal with compilation start?

Tags: emacs, elisp, valgrind, compile-mode

I use this [valgrind.el](http://www.suspectclass.com/sgifford/abandoned/emacs/valgrind.el) to run valgrind inside emacs. But the newest version of emacs has deprecated compile-internal. I don't know nearly enough about elisp to figure out how to convert the compile-internal call to a compilation-start call. This is what the original function call in question looks like:

```
(compile-internal command "No more errors" "valgrind")
```

I found this bit online that indicates possible usage of compilation-start:

```
(compilation-start command mode
         #'(lambda (mode-name) (concat "*" buf-name "*")))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about what you tried and what the results were.

As per the documentation, I would replace the compile internal line by:

```
(compilation-start command nil (lambda (mode-name) "*valgrind*"))
```